# How to get negative value of a boolean Android Manifest PlaceHolder variable?

Tags: android, gradle, manifest

Let's say I have this in my Gradle file:

```
manifestPlaceholders = [releaseBuild: "false"]
```

Now in my Android Manifest file, I want to have this:

```
<profileable android:shell="${!releaseBuild}" />
```

I am getting this error:
Cannot convert string ${!releaseBuild} to target class boolean.

Any ideas?

Comment: have you got solution to your question?